# Can't name target `dev`

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This is my Makefile:

```
catchall = echo "Available make commands: dev, rebuild" && exit 0

.DEFAULT:
    @$(catchall)

error:
    @$(catchall)

dev:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --abort-on-container-exit

rebuild:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build --abort-on-container-exit
```

When I run `make rebuild` everything works as expected, but `make dev` gives this output:

```
make: `dev' is up to date.
```

If I rename the `dev` target to pretty much anything else the command works. Why?

---

Here's the output of `make -v`:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I had a folder in the same directory called `dev`. Solution is to add `.PHONY: dev` to the Makefile.